# Load audio in myltiple time in HTML 5 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I made a online audio player. its fine but its taking too many time to start playing the audio on slow internet. Is here can i do anything to fix this problem?

can I set any loading time? like at first the audio will load first 10 second. when the first 10 second loaded the player will start plying. while it play first 10 second in that time the player will load next 10 second.? can I do it?

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src ="dir/music.mp3";
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
```

it is my current code. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Offer a low-bitrate version of the music. You can estimate loading time by loading a dummy file through XHR and measure bytes/time. If below a pre-defined threshold default the sources to low-bitrate versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best way will be to have a lower quality .mp3 file (192kbps)?
You're never sure the next 10seconds will be loaded once you've played the first 10seconds.

Comment: but it is a mp3 audio song playing site so can't use low quality file. and one file should 23 or more minute

Comment: What's the length of the song?
Perhaps you can cut a 30min song in pieces of 1min and make a playlist?

.mp3 has different qualities, like 192kbps or 320kbps (and everything in between and before)
And 192kbps is still acceptable for such a site, you can add a download button for high quality is you'd like.

Comment: say how to make pieces of 1 minute

Comment: **EDIT**
You could manually cut the audio in an audio program I meant.   
Wow, that's long :s.
I use the standard HTML and it preloads as far as I'm concerned.
Can't help you beyond this, sry mate :s


<audio controls>
  <source src="file.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Browser doesn't support the 'audio' element.
</audio>

Answer (score 0):

The Browser decides how much he will preload. You could make this like: Force the Browser to Play audio as soon the HTML is fully loaded.

```
 window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
    }
```

But slow connection is not you only enemy. If the Browser/PC is slow it may take longer because it has to load and decoding the audio. Your best bet is to use audio with lower quality. So it can load and process it faster. If you using HTML5 audio tag, make sure to use preload="auto".

```
<audio preload="auto">
```

To make advanced audio stuff you had to use low level audio frameworks and so on to have more control over how the things work.

Also .wav is way faster in decoding than .mp3.

Comment: WAV is also about x10 larger than mp3. decoding mp3 today even on slow cpus is not a big feat.

Comment: I had a really annoying delay in the music when I used mp3 in my Phaser game, with wav it was fine. So decoding had a impact even on my more or less high-end hardware. Maybe the decoder was the only reason. I don't know.